# Navigation using managed beans

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, navigation, managed-bean

i am working on a simple project in JSF 2.2 but i have some problem navigating between some pages. In the project i have a general template and all the views are template clients of that general template.

this is the view that i have troubles with:

```
<h:body>

    <ui:composition template="./LayoutGeneral.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="content">
            <p:commandButton value="Registrar Comunidad" action="#{comunidadBean.irRegisterView}"/>
        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>

</h:body>
```

In the action of the commandButton i call a method from the managed bean (Thar managed bean have other method that i call to change the page and they work fine, but this method doesnt):

(Managed Bean)

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ComunidadBean {    
    private String idComunidad;
    private String idPresidente;
    private String calle;
    private int numero;
    private int nVecinos;

    @EJB
    private ComunidadDAO ejb;

    public String register(){
        if(ejb.realizaRegistro(this)){
            return "principalView";
        } else{
            FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage ("No se pudo registrar");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("msg", fm);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String irRegisterView(){
        return "registroCView";
    }

}
```

So the method "register" works fine and the page change but the method "irRegisterView" doesnt navigate to "registroCView" page.

Does someone has any idea of what it is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can' comment, so I write this as an answer.

- I see that your bean is `SessionScoped`. You need to implement `Serializable` because a SessionScoped bean is passivating after a time.
- do you have a form in `LayoutGeneral.xhtml`? If not, this code will never works because a commandButton needs be within a form.
- why you call the method as a property? In JSF 2.2 and EL 2.3, you can call methods like this: `#{comunidadBean.isRegisterView()}`.
- Is some exception thrown when click the button? If do, paste the stack trace.

Comment: Thank you so much!! The problem was that the commandButton wasnt inside a form! I didnt know that it has to be like that!